# Angular: inheriting view in states

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In Angular/Ionic i have three different `states`:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider

    .state('layout', {
      url: "",
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: "templates/base/layout.html"
    })

    .state('layout.home', {
      url: "/home",
      views: {
        'mainContent' :{
          templateUrl: "templates/home.html"
        },
        'leftMenuContent' :{
          controller: "LeftMenuController",
          templateUrl: "templates/left-menu.html"
        }
      }
    })
    .state('layout.about', {
      url: "/about",
      views: {
        'mainContent' :{
          templateUrl: "templates/about.html",
          controller: "AboutController"
        },
        'leftMenuContent' :{
          controller: "LeftMenuController",
          templateUrl: "templates/left-menu.html"
        }
      }
    })
```

So i have an abstract state which defines the base/main layout, `home` and `about` states which have two `views`: `mainContent` and `leftMenuContent`. As for the `LeftMenuController` functionality, it just returns custom options for every route depending the `$state.current.name`.

As `leftMenuContent` will be the same for every state, is there any way to avoid defining it in every new state and inheriting it from the `layout` state (or somewhere else) instead?

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there: By calling the state `layout.home` it will inherit its views from `layout`, so this should work:

```
.state('layout', {
  url: "",
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: "templates/base/layout.html",
  views: {
    'leftMenuContent' :{
      controller: "LeftMenuController",
      templateUrl: "templates/left-menu.html"
    }
  }
})

.state('layout.home', {
  url: "/home",
  views: {
    'mainContent' :{
      templateUrl: "templates/home.html"
    }
  }
})
.state('layout.about', {
  url: "/about",
  views: {
    'mainContent' :{
      templateUrl: "templates/about.html",
      controller: "AboutController"
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, i tried to do that before asking but don't why it is not working (blank page).

Comment: Why do you have a `base-layout.html` at all? What about putting all that HTML into the `index.html` and remove the `templateUrl: "templates/base/layout.html",`

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found to be working to show nested views.

So, I have a main view in which I display my home template (`<ui-view>` in index.html), in the home template I have another `<ui-view>` in which I call different states based on what I want.

```
config(function config($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('sidemenu.home', {
                url: '/home',
                views: {
                    'topView': {
                        controller: 'HomeCtrl',
                        templateUrl: 'home/home.tpl.html'
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('sidemenu.home.list', {
                templateUrl: 'home/home-list.tpl.html'
                /*,controller: 'HomeCtrl'*/
            })
            .state('sidemenu.home.login', {
                templateUrl: 'home/home-login.tpl.html'
                /*,controller: 'HomeCtrl'*/
            })
            .state('sidemenu.home.register', {
                templateUrl: 'home/home-register.tpl.html'
                /*,controller: 'HomeCtrl'*/
            })
            .state('sidemenu.home.coach', {
                templateUrl: 'home/home-coach.tpl.html'
                /*,controller: 'HomeCtrl'*/
            })
            ;
    })

    .controller('HomeCtrl', function HomeController($scope, $rootScope, $state) {

        /**
         * ===== FIRST LOGIC =====
         **/

        //Redirect the user to the appropriate page.
        switch ($rootScope.tellState()) {
            case "ok-local":
                $state.transitionTo('sidemenu.home.list');
                break;
            case "register":
                $state.transitionTo('sidemenu.home.register');
                break;
            case "login":
                $state.transitionTo('sidemenu.home.login');
                break;
            case "coach":
                $state.transitionTo('sidemenu.home.coach');
                break;
        }
```